# How to get access to whole user object in passport

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, passport.js, passport-local

Im learning express authentication using passport and react for frontend and i have a question. How do i access whole authenticated user object?  I have db model that looks like that

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type:String,required:true },
    password: {type:String ,required:true},
    note: {type:String}
})
```

My passportConfig.js

```
const userSchema = require("./user");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
      userSchema.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (result === true) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false);
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    userSchema.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, user) => {
      const userInformation = {
        username: user.username,
      };
      cb(err, userInformation);
    });
  });
};
```

My login request and user request

```
app.post('/login',(req,res,next) => {
   passport.authenticate("local",(err,user,info) =>{
       if (err) throw err
       if(!user) res.send("No user with given login")
       else {
           req.logIn(user, (err) => {
               if (err) throw err
               res.send("Succesfully Authenticated")
           })
       }
   })(req,res,next)
})


app.get('/user',(req,res) => {
  res.send(req.user)
})
```

Now in react i want to access my logged user notes and i did this

```
const signIn = () => {
    const user = {
      username: login,
      password: password
    }

    Axios({
      method: "POST",
      data: user,
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:4000/login",
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      getNotes()
    });
      
    
  }

const getNotes = () => {
    Axios({
      method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:4000/user",
    }).then((res) => {
      setNotes(res.data);
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

In my getNotes response console.log i wanted to have all of my logged user object and i got only his username.How do i access his notes?

Answer (score 0):

The `req.user` is set from the logic within `passport.deserializeUser`. You can update deserializeUser to have more data stored within the user object.

Example to pass `notes` to created `req.user` object:

```js
passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
  userSchema.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, user) => {
    const userInformation = {
      username: user.username,
      notes: user.notes
    };
    cb(err, userInformation);
  });
});
```

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helped could you mark it as accepted?